# Can I use $rootScope for factory to update view?

Tags: angularjs

i'm started so ths is very elementar question.

I have a simple factory:

```
angular.module('notes', ['ngResource']).
factory('Notes_module', function ($resource) {
    var Notes_items = $resource(BASE_URL + 'xxx/:method/:guid', {},
        {
            get_all: {method: 'GET', params: {method: 'get_all'}, isArray: true }
        });

    return Notes_items;
}
);
```

and controller to show note_items.

```
function Notes($scope, Notes_module) {
     $scope.notes = Notes_module.get_all();
};
```

Now in my view I have simple button to get new notes_items from server:

```
<a ng-click="synchronize()">
```

and the controller:

```
function LeftBardController($scope, Queries_module) {
$scope.synchronize = function() {
    $scope.notes = Queries_module.get_all_new_note();
};
```

}

the new factory for check new items:

```
angular.module('queries', ['ngResource']).
factory('Queries_module', function ($resource) {
    var Queries_items = $resource(BASE_URL + 'xxx/:method/:guid', {},
        {
          get_all_new_note: {method: 'GET', params: {method: 'get_all_trash'}, isArray: true },
        });

    return Queries_items;
}
);
```

**And the question is.**

When I click on button 'synchronize' the database are updated ok.But the view are not refresh. When I refresh page then the view are also refresh.

When I change $scope in my controller to $rootScope (save notes in rootscope) it automatically refresh view as i want and it's great - but it is a good way to use $rootScope. How can i do this in other way ?
I read about $apply but when add it to my controller i does not work.

Comment: As described in the tutorial you need to use the callback of the resource method and set the data inside then. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Comment: What I realy need was comunication beatween controller. I found great tuturial about this if anyone can help (like help me): http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/